# Place ListView item at the center of the visible region

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, centering

I have a `ListView` which contains an `ArrayAdapter` which contains items for each hour of the day, and I need it to place the item which contains the current hour in the center of the visible region of the ListView.

I've tried `setSelection`, but it will place the item on the top instead of the center.

Is there any method to do it without calculating layout heights and such?

Right now I'm using this method, because I know the items are 40dip tall, but they won't always be 40dip tall.

```
private void centerListView() {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    final int listViewProgrammerPixels = listViewProgrammer.getHeight();
    final int itemPixels = (int) (40 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
    final int pixelsFromTop = (listViewProgrammerPixels - itemPixels) / 2;
    listViewProgrammer.setSelectionFromTop(hour, pixelsFromTop);
}
```

Comment: Show the list item code .show your code

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this. Need to see the code

Comment: You could copy the contents of that item into another `View` and then set its `gravity` property to `center`.

Comment: Edited my question with the current way I'm doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this using this logic first you have to get height of ListView and the height of View in adapter getView method then write this code in your click event .

int offset = ((listViewheight / 2) - (viewHeight / 2));

mListView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position,Math.abs(offset));

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this property `item_layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);`